# GCM - Never enter onMessage() with Android 4.0 Device

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am not very experienced with Android development and I shall include gcm to an existing app. 
So far, I can register all devices and I receive the registrationId. The problem is, that I never enter the onMessage() method on my Android 4.0 device. I also tried it with a Galaxy Note 2 (Android 4.1) and there I can receive the message. 
I don't get any error message, I just never enter onMessage().

When I send the message, I always get an messageId, so gcm "accepted" the message. But it is never delivered to the device.

How can I find out what the problem is??? Thanks in advance

GCMIntentService.java

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

public GCMIntentService() {
    super("82........");
}

@Override
protected void onError(Context arg0, String error) {
    System.out.println("Not able to register or unregister because: "
            + error);

}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

    System.out.println("GCM DELIVERED MESSAGE TO DEVICE:" + message);
}

@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String regId) {
    System.out.println("Device is registered  with RegisterId: " + regId);
}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String regId) {
    System.out.println("Device with RegisterId: " + regId
            + " has unregistered");
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    System.out.println("Entered onRecoverableError");
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}
}
```

My Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.activities"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.activities.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.activities.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- Activity which is called first to decide which Activity comes next -->
    <activity
        android:name=".StartUp"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_start_up" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayContent"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_content" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AllSigns"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_all_signs" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.activities" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

</application>
```

Code in onCreate() of my first activity (Startup.java)

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

if (regId.equals("")) {
System.out.println("Id ist leer, Device wird neu registriert");
GCMRegistrar.register(this, "825134311331");
} else {
System.out.println("This device is already registered");
}
```

Comment: In the code you posted I do not see you sending your registration ID to your Application Server, are you doing this? Also post what GCM is returning to you when you send the message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying this over WIFI, make sure that port 5228 isn't being blocked by the network. That's how I fixed the problem that I had after more days of trying to get it to work than I'd like to admit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the GCMIntentService class is in the package specified in your manifest